# How to consume the last 5 minutes data in Kafka using confluent kakfa python package?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

I am currently able to consume the lastest real-time data in kafka but is there a way to consume the last 5 mins data in each partition in an optimized way?

The current way of doing this is setting `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` and then consuming till it reaches the end of the offset in each partion that lies in the 5 minute timestamp. But this takes a long time.

If there is a way to do this but in reverse order so as to reduce the cosumption time, it would be really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The [`confluent_kafka.Consumer.offsets_for_times()`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.offsets_for_times) function provides a mechanism to obtain the earliest offsets for `TopicPartition` objects where the timestamps are greater than or equal to a POSIX timestamp provided in milliseconds.

You could register a callback function for the `on_assign` event when subscribing to your topic(s) that uses `Consumer.offsets_for_times()` and [`Consumer.assign()`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/html/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.assign) to reset offsets on your assigned partitions to the desired positions prior to consuming messages.

For example, you might do something like this:

```py
import datetime
import math
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, TopicPartition

def get_time_offset():
  '''Returns the POSIX epoch representation (in milliseconds) of the datetime 5 minutes prior to being called'''
  delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)  
  now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)  # TZ-aware object to simplify POSIX epoch conversion
  prior = now - delta  
  return math.floor(prior.timestamp() * 1000)  # convert seconds to milliseconds for Consumer.offsets_for_times()

def reset_offsets(consumer, partitions):
  '''Resets the offsets of the provided partitions to the first offsets found corresponding to timestamps greater than or equal to 5 minutes ago.'''
  time_offset = get_time_offset()
  search_partitions = [TopicPartition(p.topic, p.partition, time_offset) for p in partitions]  # new TPs with offset= time_offset
  time_offset_partitions = consumer.offsets_for_times(search_partitions)  # find TPs with timestamp of earliest offset >= time_offset
  consumer.assign(time_offset_partitions)  # (re-)set consumer partition assignments and start consuming

topics = ['my-topic-of-interest']

c = Consumer({
  'bootstrap.servers': 'server-fqdn',
  'group.id': 'group-name'
})

c.subscribe(topics, on_assign=reset_offsets)  # reset_offsets() called when partition assignment received after c.poll()

# Process all messages from reset offsets (5 min. ago) to present (and ongoing)
while True:
  try:
    msg = c.poll()  # first call triggers execution of on_assign callback function, resetting offsets
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print("Consumer is closed.")
    break
  # process message and commit...

c.close()
```